# ASP NET MVC Добавление элементов в список во View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть модель:

```
public class ProjectModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Add_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime End_Date { get; set; }
    ...
    public string File { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public List<DeviceListModel> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

Есть форма Create, где заполняются поля проекта. В каждом проекте есть список устройств. **Как добавлять во View новые устройства в список, чтоб при отправке формы полностью получить объект проекта со списком устройств?**

Если добавлять через JS например, в таблицу, то данные попадают просто на страницу, но не в объект  `List<DeviceListModel> Devices`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я реализовал без post формы и отправляю данные через AJAX. С помощью [примера](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-add-rows-to-HTML-Table-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx) 
Это работает хорошо. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что я не вижу полный путь до прикрепляемого файла, чтоб его сохранить на сервер. Вижу `C:\fakepath\file.pdf`
Поэтому думаю вернуться к отправке post формы, в которой будет отправлять и файл.

Comment: Думаю сделать нечто такое
`<input name="Devices[0].Name"/>
<input name="Devices[0].Sum"/>`
И добавлять их скриптом, меняя индекс в `[]`. Попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так:
В контроллере инициализировал список определенного размера, заранее больше, чем ожидается

```
view.Project.Devices = new List<DeviceListModel>(100);
```

При нажатии на кнопку + срабатывает скрипт, в котором

```
//Add Name cell.
var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
var deviceName = $("<input />");
deviceName.attr("type", "input");
deviceName.attr("readonly", "readonly");
deviceName.attr("name", "Project.Devices[" + countDevices + "].Name");
deviceName.attr("value", selectDevice.val());
cell.append(deviceName);
countDevices = countDevices + 1;
```

В результате формируется html

```
<input type="input" readonly="readonly" name="Project.Devices[0].Name" value="Dev2">
<input type="input" readonly="readonly" name="Project.Devices[1].Name" value="Dev1">
```

При отправке формы в объект попадают эти данные.